# Filter on terms aggregation in transform elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I created a transform which is grouped on products and has a term seller, so that I can search product statistics based on a seller. A snippet of the transform is shown here:

```
"pivot": {
  "group_by": {
    "product_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "offer.product.id"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
     "seller_names": {
       "terms": {
         "field": "offer.seller.name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

What I want to do now is search product statistics by seller name as follows:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "seller_names.*"
      ],
      "analyze_wildcard": true,
      "default_operator": "AND",
      "query": "*"
    }
  }
}
```

I used a wildcard in this example (I know its expensive). However, this does not return any results. My preview looks as follows:

```
{
  "preview" : [
    {
      "product_id" : 1,
      "seller_names" : {
        "adsf" : 1,
        "asdfasdf" : 5,
        "test" : 2,
        "aa33as" : 32
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I add seller names to a transform that is grouped by product and search on those seller names?

EDIT:

I changed my strategy with terms by adding a scripted metric that returns all sellers as an array. This makes it possible to search over that array with a query string.

```
  "sellers": {
    "scripted_metric": {
      "init_script": "state.sellers = [];",
      "map_script": """
      def current_seller = doc['offer.seller.name'].getValue();
      if (!state.sellers.contains(current_seller))
      {
        state.sellers.add(current_seller);
      }""",
      "combine_script": "return state",
      "reduce_script": """
      def values = [];
      for (s in states) {
        if (s.sellers.size() >= values.size()) {
          values = s.sellers;
      }}
      return values
      """
    }
  }
```

However, this gives the following results when compared to a terms query.

Scripted metric:

```
  "sellers" : [
    "a",
    "d",
    "c",
    "b"
  ],
```

Terms query:
"seller_names" : {
"e" : 1,
"c" : 1,
"b" : 4,
"d" : 2,
"a" : 299
}

How do I make sure all sellers are returned in my scripted metric? Or is there another way to solve this? I am currently using elasticsearch 7.13.3. Do I need to upgrade to 7.14 and use top_metrics?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding the following scripted metric:

```
"sellers": {
    "scripted_metric": {
      "init_script": "state.sellers = [];",
      "map_script": """
      def current_seller = doc['offer.seller.name'].getValue();
      if (!state.sellers.contains(current_seller))
      {
        state.sellers.add(current_seller);
      }""",
      "combine_script": "return state",
      "reduce_script": """
      def values = [];
      for (s in states) 
      {
        for (seller in s.sellers) 
        {
          if (!values.contains(seller)) 
          {
            values.add(seller);
          }
        }
      }
      return values
      """
```

This returns an array of sellers, which can then be queried over with my initial query string.

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "sellers"
      ],
      "analyze_wildcard": true,
      "default_operator": "AND",
      "query": "*"
    }
  }
}
```